# What makes xml-serialization different from sending as string?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-serialization

I tried to figure out the way to serialize xml file before sending it over the network, but in vain. I could temporarily accomplish the task by just reading the xml contents, put it in a string and send the string over the network and write the content into an xml file at the other end. Now, it makes me wonder what could the major difference between xml-serialization and this method be?

This question might be very trivial, but i still cannot see the reasons.

Comment: There is no need to serialize XML because it is already serial. You can talk of serializing something else *as* XML, but serializing XML doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

XML serialization is typically the process of taking an XML document and making it into a string so you can do things like send it over the network or write it to a file. (Technically speaking, you can serialize it in different ways, but making it into a string is pretty much always what you do when you want to exchange the document between systems)

So there shouldn't be much practical difference in sending a serialized version of your XML document, or sending an already stringified version of your document that you've obtained from some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I my mind, serialization is the method of taking program data as stored in various structures in RAM and creating a single contiguous block of memory with sufficient detailed content to recreate said structures.

This block of memory can then be easily sent over a network, saved to file etc. At the other end, we can now deserialize the data back into the original structures.

The serialized block of memory may contain binary data (often of a [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) form). Alternatively, the memory block may be a human readable string. XML is very often used as a human readable form of data suitable for transmission over a network.

For this reason, when you say XML serialization, I understand this as the process of taking you binary representation of XML data and turning it into an XML document suitable for either saving to disk or transmission over a network.